# Symfony 2 - Form Entity Type: How to format the generated drop-down?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form that shows a drop-down menu of categories to choose from.

These categories are setup using the Gedmo Tree Extension, so a category can have child categories.

I have a custom query in the form builder that selects only the categories that belong to a specific group. However, I need to be able to show in the drop-down which categories are parents and which are children, e.g.

```
Parent Category 1
  -- Child Category A
  -- Child Category B
Parent Category2
  -- Child Category C
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Also, how can I pass a variable to my query_builder, from the controller that is calling the formtype?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to select the parent you can use the optgroup tag

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Category 1">
        <option>Option 1...</option>
        <option>Option 2...</option>
        <option>Option 3...</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Category 2">
        <option>Option 1...</option>
        <option>Option 2...</option>
        <option>Option 3...</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Edit:

Symfony 2 supports the optgroup tag with arrays *(untested, may contain errors)*:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $category_choices = array(
        array('Category 1' => array(
            '1' => 'Option 1...',
            '2' => 'Option 2...',
            '3' => 'Option 3...'
        )),
        array('Category 2' => array(
            '4' => 'Option 4...',
            '5' => 'Option 5...'
        ))
    );

    $builder->add('category_list', 'choice', array(
        'label' => 'Category',
        'choices' => $category_choices
    ));
}
```

Comment: Sadly it isn't that simple. Symfony2 handles how the <select> tag is rendered and it would take a heck of a lot to be able to add in <optgroups> :(

Comment: Well, the code inside the function is ok, just it is in the wrong place. Get a look at the answer [to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244376/select-with-optgroup-in-symfony-2-0). However, +1 for the research effort!

Answer (score 1):

A few days ago I was looking to accomplish exactly the same thing ! I used Neurofr solution here : 
[Symfony2,Doctrine Extensions Tree : Generating a "tree"-like dropdown Select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309959/symfony2-doctrine-extensions-tree-generating-a-tree-like-dropdown-select-lis)

And it's work.
Now I will try to deactivate all options that got last children from the tree.

Comment: I found the same answer too, just the other day :)

Answer (score 0):

Extend Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\EntityChoiceList and use it in formBuilder, for ex:

```
$formBuilder
      ->add('parent', 'entity',
            array(
              'label' => 'Parent',
              'em' => $em,
              'class' => 'w3des\\Bundle\\SiteBundle\\Entity\\Menu',
              'choice_list' => new MenuChoiceList($em, $group, $cfg['tree']),
              'required' => false,
              'empty_value' => '----'
            ));
```

You have to overwrite: getEntity(), getEntities(), getIdentifierValues() and probably constructor too