# Select with optgroup in Symfony 2.0

Tags: php, forms, symfony, html-select, optgroup

In **Symfony2**, the `select` html component is rendered as a `ChoiceType` object, which is used indeed also for `checkboxes` and `radiobuttons`.

Does someone *really* know **how to render a select with the optgroup option in Symfony2**?

For sake of completeness, here I report an example of a *select* with the **optgroup** tag (example from [w3cschools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)):

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Moreover, notice that there is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351423/symfony-2-form-entity-type-how-to-format-the-generated-drop-down), but the answers are not convincing.

Comment: It seems to be fixed in sf2.1 ([see the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by)). Are you using sf2.0 or sf2.1?

Comment: SF2.0! But SF2.1 is at RC2 now! So, it is better to wait for the first 2.1 stable release... Should I cancel the question?

Comment: No don't close, there might have a workaround to have optgroup on sf2.0, but I don't know it.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know If I will migrate to Symfony2.1. I don't know how much effort will be required doing the porting of the projects and plugins!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Do this:

```
$car_choices = array(
    'Swedish Cars' => array(
        'volvo' => 'Volvo',
        'saab' => 'Saab',
    ),
    'German Cars' => array(
        'mercedes' => 'Mercedes',
        'audi' => 'Audi'
    )
);

$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('car', 'choice', array(
            'label' => 'Choose your car',
            'choices' => $car_choices,
            ))
        ->getForm();
```

Works for Symfony 2.0.x

Comment: Much like in symfony 1.x: array of array.

Comment: Perfect! Great alternative for using the entities.

Answer (score 16):

It depends how your Entity is defined and how you group your entity. Assuming the grouping is done given a parameter in your object, let's say "brand". You can do:

```php
$builder->add('cars', null, array(
  'group_by'=> 'brand'
));
```

Comment: how about self referencing. like Category and Sub Category?

Comment: @Daskul sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: self referencing relationship. you have an entity that has reference to the same entity type as its parent. Like on Category. I want all my categories in one database table but still able to make hierarchies. Ex. I will create category of Computer, Laptop, Desktop but I want Laptop and Desktop under the COmputer category

Comment: I would say this is not possible. Mainly because it is not allowed in HTML to nest `<optgroup>` element (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup "Note: Optgroup elements may not be nested.")