# Entity mapping in a Symfony2 choice field with optgroup

Tags: forms, symfony, entities

Suppose to have an entity in **Symfony2** that has a field `bestfriend`, which is a `User` entity selected from a list of `User` entities that satisfy a complex requirement. 
You can render this field in a form by specifying that it is an [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#basic-usage), i.e.:

```
$builder->add('bestfriend', 'entity', array(
   'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
   'property' => 'username',
));
```

This form field is rendered as a  `<select>`, where each one of the displayed values is in the form:

```
<option value="user_id">user_username</option>
```

So, one would render the field by using the `<optgroup>` tags to highlight such special feature of the friends.

Following this principle, I created a field type, namely `FriendType`, that creates the array of choices as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244376/select-with-optgroup-in-symfony-2-0), which is rendered as follows:

```
$builder->add('bestfriend', new FriendType(...));
```

The `FriendType` class creates a `<select>` organized with the same `<option>`s but organized under `<optgroup>`s.

Here I come to the problem! When submitting the form, the framework recognize that the user field is not an instance of User, but it is an integer. **How can I let Symfony2 understand that the passed int is the id of an entity of type User?**

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand you question, but I think you might solve it with DataTransformer

Comment: @nikita2206 Get a look to my own answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here follows my solution.
Notice that it is not mentioned in the *Symfony2 official docs*, but it works! I exploited the fact that the entity field type [is child of `choice`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

Hence, you can just pass the array of `choices` as a param.

```
$builder->add('bestfriend', 'entity', array(
   'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
   'choices' => $this->getArrayOfEntities()
));
```

where the function `getArrayOfEntities()` is a function that fills the choice list with the friends of my friends, organized by my friends:

```
private function getArrayOfEntities(){
    $repo = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeHelloBundle:User');
    $friends = $repo->findAllFriendByComplexCriteria(...);
    $list = array();
    foreach($friends as $friend){
        $name = $friend->getUsername();
        if(count($friend->getFriends())>0){
            $list[$name] = array();
            foreach($friend->getFriends() as $ff){
                $list[$name][$ff->getUsername()] = $ff;
            }
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
```

I know the example could be meaningless, but it works...

PS: You need to pass the entity manager to let it working...

Comment: is there any way we can do it in the finishView method?