# Symfony Form Dropdown

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to display "State and Region" in single dropdown like "StateName - RegionName". but in this code how can i add multiple property(field) and how to join 2 tables. (both state and region fields comes from different table)

```
$optionArray = array(
"class"         => "Bundle:State",
"property"      => "state",
"em"            => "default",
"label"         => "State:",
"attr"          => $attr,
"query_builder" => function( EntityRepository $er ) {
return $er->createQueryBuilder( "s" )->where( "s.isActive = 1" )->orderBy( "s.state","ASC" );
},
'required'      => false,
'empty_value'   => 'All'
);
$builder->add( "state", "entity", $optionArray );
```

Answer (score 1):

### how to join 2 tables

If you set the correct orm relations you don't need to make a join, you could simply do

```
$state->getRegions();
```

Read [**Entity Relationships/Associations**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations).

### "State and Region" in single dropdown

This often means that you want to group options in optgroup. But you do not make this clear in your question. **[Select with optgroup in Symfony 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244376/select-with-optgroup-in-symfony-2-0)**