# Symfony 2: multiple choices hierarchical form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony 2 and I'm building a site where I have a list of competences that the user can choose. I have succesfully built a form with the list of competences as checkboxes, however, the competences are ordered hierarchically, so I would like to show them using nested  lists.

I have tried using a customized form field this way:

```
{% block _useredit_competences_widget %}
    {% for choice in choices %}
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

but the competences are in the plain array `choices` where I only can print the name, so I don't have access to the parents or children.

Any clue how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have to be able to select only leafs or also the "parent" elements?

Comment: Only leaves, though the parents must be shown.

Comment: is the solution provided in this issue an option:[Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351423/symfony-2-form-entity-type-how-to-format-the-generated-drop-down). There they also use a plain array. But im not sure what happens if you want to select multiple entries, but its worth trying. Since I dont know how your array looks like, maybe you can provide the data behind your postet view.

Comment: I don't think that's working for me because using that I can only redefine the way you render one element, but can't render them hierarchically. The structure is just a three level array where the indexes are the parent competences and the values are the children. Just the regular way to nest categories.